# Are there any performance bottle necks in template inheritance?

Tags: django, performance, inheritance

Are there any performance bottlenecks in template inheritance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loader-types) have an excellent explanation of this:

> By default, the templating system will
> read and compile your templates every
> time they need to be rendered. While
> the Django templating system is quite
> fast, the overhead from reading and
> compiling templates can add up.
>
> The cached template loader is a
> class-based loader that you configure
> with a list of other loaders that it
> should wrap. The wrapped loaders are
> used to locate unknown templates when
> they are first encountered. The cached
> loader then stores the compiled
> Template in memory. The cached
> Template instance is returned for
> subsequent requests to load the same
> template.
>
> For example, to enable template caching with the filesystem and app_directories template loaders you might use the following settings:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', (
        'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
        'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    )),
)
```